# Trouble initializing SDK node using USB-TTL M210 v2

Tags: linux, usb, ros, dji-sdk, udev

I am trying to connect M210 v2 RTK to a desktop computer with Ubuntu 18.04, ROS Melodic and parallel installation of Opencv 3.3.1 and 4.5.3 using a USB-TTL RS232 to make UART connection and an USB-USB connecting drone and desktop to be able to run Advanced Sensing.

When I call `ls -l /dev/ttyACM* && ls -l /dev/ttyUSB*` it returns that it is indentified the USB and ACM connection.

```
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166, 0 out  4 13:18 /dev/ttyACM0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 out  4 13:18 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

I also set the transfer rate of TTL-USB to 921600 using `minicom`, and gave persmission to device to read and write with `sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER && sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0`

Unfortunatelly when I launch `roslaunch dji_osdk_ros dji_sdk_node.launch` it appears some connection problem presented below and I am not being able to fix it. I have been trying to turn on/off drone and RC several times ass described [here](https://forum.dji.com/thread-216529-1-1.html), but the problem still stand.

```
started roslaunch server http://V3D06:43613/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /dji_sdk/acm_name: /dev/ttyACM0
 * /dji_sdk/align_time: False
 * /dji_sdk/app_id: 1076017
 * /dji_sdk/app_version: 1
 * /dji_sdk/baud_rate: 921600
 * /dji_sdk/dxc: False
 * /dji_sdk/enc_key: 6bd1d26f8dd897e4b...
 * /dji_sdk/serial_name: /dev/ttyUSB0
 * /dji_sdk/use_broadcast: False
 * /rosdistro: melodic
 * /rosversion: 1.14.12

NODES
  /
    dji_sdk (dji_osdk_ros/dji_sdk_node)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [2436]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to bde7b4d2-252e-11ec-8a59-1831bfb3e154
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [2458]
started core service [/rosout]
process[dji_sdk-2]: started with pid [2464]
[ INFO] [1633364323.534426789]: Advanced Sensing is Enabled on M210.
Read App ID
User Configuration read successfully. 

[1276751.089]STATUS/1 @ getDroneVersion, L1702: ret = 0
[1276751.089]STATUS/1 @ parseDroneVersionInfo, L1122: Device Serial No. = 1DADG3E00100U4
[1276751.089]STATUS/1 @ parseDroneVersionInfo, L1124: Firmware = 3.4.3.44
[1276751.089]STATUS/1 @ functionalSetUp, L279: Shake hand with drone successfully by getting drone version.
[1276751.089]STATUS/1 @ legacyX5SEnableTask, L56: Legacy X5S Enable task created.
[1276752.089]STATUS/1 @ sendHeartbeatToFCTask, L1576: OSDK send heart beat to fc task created.
[1276752.289]STATUS/1 @ Control, L40: The control class is going to be deprecated.It will be better to use the FlightController class instead!
[1276752.290]STATUS/1 @ FileMgrImpl, L253: register download file callback handler successfully.
[1276753.557]STATUS/1 @ PSDKModule, L98: MOP only support M300, so mop client will not be initialized here.
[1276753.557]STATUS/1 @ PSDKModule, L98: MOP only support M300, so mop client will not be initialized here.
[1276753.557]STATUS/1 @ PSDKModule, L98: MOP only support M300, so mop client will not be initialized here.
[1276753.557]STATUS/1 @ initDJIHms, L900: DJI HMS is not supported on this platform!

[1276753.567]STATUS/1 @ getDroneVersion, L1702: ret = 0
[1276753.567]STATUS/1 @ parseDroneVersionInfo, L1122: Device Serial No. = 1DADG3E00100U4
[1276753.567]STATUS/1 @ parseDroneVersionInfo, L1124: Firmware = 3.4.3.44
[1276753.567]STATUS/1 @ AdvancedSensing, L145: Advanced Sensing init for the M210 drone
[1276753.567]STATUS/1 @ init, L49: Looking for USB device...

[1276753.572]STATUS/1 @ init, L65: Found 8 USB devices, identifying DJI device...

[1276753.572]STATUS/1 @ init, L83: Found a DJI device...

[1276753.572]STATUS/1 @ init, L96: Attempting to open DJI USB device...

[1276753.572]ERRORLOG/1 @ init, L101: Failed to open DJI USB device...

[1276753.572]ERRORLOG/1 @ init, L102: Error code: -3
[1276753.572]ERRORLOG/1 @ init, L105: Please make sure you provide a udev file for your system and reboot the computer
[1276753.573]STATUS/1 @ LiveViewImpl, L89: Finding if liveview stream is available now.
[1276754.076]STATUS/1 @ init, L254: Start advanced sensing initalization
[1276754.076]STATUS/1 @ activate, L1329: version 0x304032C

[1276754.076]STATUS/1 @ adv_pthread, L46: adv pthread created !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
[1276754.076]STATUS/1 @ adv_pthread, L48: adv pthread running !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
[dji_sdk-2] process has died [pid 2464, exit code -11, cmd /home/vant3d/catkin_ws/devel/lib/dji_osdk_ros/dji_sdk_node __name:=dji_sdk __log:=/home/vant3d/.ros/log/bde7b4d2-252e-11ec-8a59-1831bfb3e154/dji_sdk-2.log].
log file: /home/vant3d/.ros/log/bde7b4d2-252e-11ec-8a59-1831bfb3e154/dji_sdk-2*.log
```

It appears it has some problem providing a udev file, but I don't know how to fix it. Does anyone have some idea to help on this problems?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That's my post. Firstly turn off advanced sensing to try whether a basic FTDI works.

The second which DJI OSDK version are you using? does the OSDK version match the version in OSDK-ROS? I saw you have M300 in. that is usually in OSDK 4+. For M210, I only use 3.8 and 3.9

If basic FTDI works, and you can get all the feedback. there is a higher chance that you have the wrong ACM config. DJI RNDIS thing is nasty and may not be config properly. You need to manually set static IP of 192.168.43.1 (or I remember something like this 42 or 43, you need to check on this static IP) and set it manually